# Use AccessibilityNodeInfo to turn switch on and off

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

Okay, so I want to know if it is possible to use AccessibilityService/AccessibilityNodeInfo to turn an android.widget.Switch on/off? Here is my current code and it works to click the text on the screen, but it does not turn a switch on/off.

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();

if (source == null) {
        return;
    }

    Log.v(TAG, "Event happened");
    processUI(source);
}
```

And of course, the processUI does everything like compares package, text, etc. and sends it all to clickScreen where it actually clicks the screen.

```
protected void clickScreen(AccessibilityNodeInfo source, final String text, final String type, final int length)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "Clicking: " + source + " / " + text + " / " + type + " / " + length);
    if (text == null)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Text is NULL");
        return;
    }

    List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = source.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(text);
    for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SHOULD BE CLICKING: " + node);
        node.performAction(4);
        node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
    }

    list = source
            .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(text);
    for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MIGHT BE CLICKING: " + node);
        node.performAction(4);
        node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is source going to be in the function you wrote? Why are you clicking on multiple elements up to four times? Which one of these "nodes" that the click action is performed on is expected to be the switch?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @IshaanGarg yes I did. I had to use some `if statements` and remove `node.performAction(4);` So that way it only clicked one time. Then I would get the class I was trying to click from `.getClassName()` so it only clicked on the switch.

Comment: I got it to work by clicking on the parent container layout. Now I'm stuck in getting the service to perform a swipe action, and that's not even possible I guess..

Comment: @IshaanGarg start a thread and post some code, I will see what I can do to help you get it to work.